# Why doesn't Google Cloud Run require runtimes as AWS Lambda does?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, google-cloud-run

AWS Lambda requires a specific [RUNTIME](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/lambda-runtimes.html) to act as a broker between the hosted container apps and the Lambda service. Why doesn't Google Cloud Run require such a runtime? What are the pros/cons and technological implications of that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

They're two different products.  Lambda would be similar to [Cloud Functions](https://cloud.google.com/functions), and you would need to specify a runtime.

[Cloud Run](https://cloud.google.com/run), on the other hand, is more like ECS Fargate. It runs containers, so in a sense your runtime would be whatever your container is running whether it be Python or NodeJS, etc.